# Can I use the 3rd conditional that way?

Tags: conditionals, subjunctive-mood, conditional-perfect, perfect-aspect, sequence-of-tenses

Is the sentence given below grammatically correct?

> Had you born two days later and it would have been difficult to celebrate your birthdays.

Is it the only option to use the *third conditional* to express such a situation?

Comment: As Bill reports, if one half of the conditional is in a perfect construction, than the other half must be also; otherwise it won’t balance.  I’m not sure what your first language is — perhaps something that isn’t Western European? — but the ones I know all also work this way.

Comment: @tchrist Yes, you're right, my native languages have similar tense constructions. They are Eastern European:)

Comment: Is it true that "3rd conditional" is a term used only in ESL so that most users of this forum won't know what it means?

Comment: Yes, it's true. Someone has been creative about teaching English without checking English grammar. This is not the way English works, and these websites are full of incorrect nonsense about English. Like where one must use "future tense". Hopeless. Useless.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your sentence is grammatically incorrect. It should be:

> Had you been born two days later, it would have been difficult to celebrate your birthday.

You can also say it this way:

> If you had been born two days later, it would have been difficult to celebrate your birthday.

Illiterate native speakers will say things like:

> If you would {have / of} been born two days later, it would have been difficult to celebrate your birthday.

But that's ungrammatical

Comment: By asking about alternatives I meant using the 2nd conditional. But I think it's wrong. Thank you for your examples!

Comment: I thought I could use *and* conjunction omitting the comma.

Comment: Just an aside: I’m still not convinced that these so-called “numbered conditionals” really help anyone; native speakers never learn this sort of thing, and employ many more forms than just those three alone.  I can sometimes see why the ESL teachers  take these shortcuts, but often I cannot.

Comment: @tchrist What do you mean by *ESL teachers take these shortcuts*?

Comment: @brick: I never learned that terminology, so I can't write a 2nd conditional sentence without looking up what it means. When I was a kid, we had subjunctives & conditionals, unreal conditions and real conditions. Reading terminology I'm not familiar with doesn't help me understand what's being talked about, but I know how to use the language.

Comment: @brick: He means that it's easier to teach conditionals when it's broken down into categories: first conditional, second conditional, etc.  But it's not something that native English speakers learn.  I only know it from teaching English to non-native speakers.

Comment: @brick There are something like a dozen or more if/then forms in English, of which these three shortcutty versions that ESL teachers have come to recently use are but a small sampling — and indeed, do not collectively constitute a majority of real-world corpus uses compared with the other ones. I am not certain, but I believe that ESL teachers present this “simplified version of reality” to try forestall invalid sequence-of-tense combos by non-native learners, but the harm they do is making their students believe that these “rules” are  all there is to the matter.

Comment: Recently I've read a book [written by Michael Swan](http://books.google.com.ua/books/about/Practical_English_usage.html?id=eJ5AAQAAIAAJ&redir_esc=y) which covers advanced topics including conditionals.

Comment: Whoa, whoa, whoa there. Ungrammatical-native- speaker? A discouraged non-standard dialect maybe, but it's a -different- grammar, not ungrammatical.

Comment: @Mitch: It's ungrammatical in standard English (whatever that may be). Do you say things like "If I would of been born earlier,..."? Claiming that such solecisms are examples of a "different grammar" is merely the misguided politics of inclusion. We aren't talking about AAVE here, which is a recognized rule-governed dialect of English. Being a native speaker doesn't confer linguistic infallibility, only the ability to form natural sentences & understand the basics of the grammar without knowing how to discuss it. Illiteracy & ignorance exist. Alternative grammaticality is a bad political joke.

Comment: @Mitch: The OP wants to pass an English test. Using "discouraged non-standard dialect" will not help him do that. It's a disservice to EFL students to teach them political correctness & claim that incorrect English is grammatical. The IELTS, TOEFL, & TOEIC tests don't measure PC, only one's knowledge of standard English. Save the politics for other native speakers. I don't give a damn myself. I speak & write whatever's appropriate for the context of my discourse. EFL students can't do that. They want to learn what's correct to pass tests, not what's fuzzy egalitarian to be morally good.

Comment: _I_ would use that construction 'If I would of...' but certainly not in speech or writing for more formal audiences. The best thing here would be to give the nuance (e.g. 'Don't use this in a formal situation'). This ain't political correctness, it is how people talk sometimes. We can tell them what's right for the test, but also we have the ability here to tell them that not everyone follows those rules everyday and there are alternatives they'll hear. ELL is for short oversimplified rules. Also, I think I just heard you say that AAVE, an 'alternative grammaticality', is a bad political joke.

Comment: @Mitch: That's the trouble with politics (another form of religion): people hear what they want to hear. Read my comment again: "AAVE ... is a recognized rule-governed dialect of English". "Alternative grammaticality" is using "I would of" & thinking that it's anything but an illiterate & ignorant solecism, regardless of the audience. But if you hang out with the illiterate & ignorant, den yuh gotta jaw lak dem guyz doo. EFL students know that native speakers of their own language also make speaking & writing errors. I would **never** use "If I would of...". Each to its own.

Comment: @BillFranke: What would your position be if you found out that "If I would of..." were AAVE?

Comment: @Mitch: The same as for "I be doin' that": it must be identified as normal for AAVE speakers but ungrammatical in standard English. I don't teach anything but standard international English. I always identify **contested usages** & explain what's "correct" on standard English tests (what EFL students **usually** want) & how that's different from what people might really say in everyday English. All usages have a dynamic social value **in context**: to deny that is politics or stupidity. "It's OK because I use it" (my idiolect is only mine) isn't an option. Neither are moralistic hypotheticals.

Answer (score 1):

The third conditional is for things in the past that cannot be changed, so you are correct to use it in this case.  This is the only type of conditional statement that deals with the past, so you are correct to choose it.  There is no other way to express your example sentence without changing some of the meaning.

I would correct two small things in the sentence you gave.  First, the word 'and' is not necessary in conditional statements to link the two parts of the sentence.  Second, a comma should be inserted between the condition and the result.

So the corrected sentence looks like this:

> Had you been born two days later, it would have been difficult to celebrate your birthdays.

Another minor issue is that it would sound more natural to say the singular 'birthday', rather than 'birthdays', although it's not incorrect to use the plural.

[This page](http://www.ehow.com/info_8404380_four-various-forms-conditional-statements.html) describes the different types of conditional statements.

[This page](http://www.englishclub.com/grammar/verbs-conditional_4.htm) goes into more detail about the third conditional and its structure.